# How to set wallpaper in Flutter images in pexels API

Tags: android, flutter

The below Dart code is for a full-screen image. Can I get some help on how to I get it to set an image loaded from Pexels API a as wallpaper?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Global.dart';

class Fullimage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FullimageState createState() => _FullimageState();
}

class _FullimageState extends State<Fullimage> {
  PageController pageController = new PageController(initialPage: Global.index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
        controller: pageController,
        itemCount: Global.photos.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(Global.photos[index].src.large2x),
                fit: BoxFit.cover
              )
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When replacing your `Global.photos[index].src.large2x` with another image url your code works without a problem. What is the error that you are getting? Share the log with us.